# CKEditor hide table border

Tags: html, css, ckeditor, yui-pure-css

I have full-page CKEditor, which is use to edit my Invoices.
My CSS have table border property, and I can see it when load HTML source directly in browser. 
But CKEditor hide it after open! I even see how it blinks for one second, than fade. Anybody faced with such problem?

Here example of my invoice:
http://jsbin.com/ludicohuxe/edit?html,output

```
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  }  

  td {
  padding: 1em;
  }
```

Comment: where is your ckeditor/??

Comment: in my 'public' folder. (php laravel project). But I see CKeditor, i only didn't see border.

Comment: try `!important` option for border style. 'border: 1px solid black !important;'

Comment: Whoa, Prabhakaran, this works! Thank you!

Comment: Fix the styles in ckeditors contents.css, dont add styles that override with !important!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
border: 1px solid black !important;
```